# ModelState.IsValid is false when binded to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Model:

faculty class

```
[Key]
[Required(ErrorMessage="*Enter Faculty id")]
[StringLength(5)]
public string Id { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="*Enter First Name")]
[MaxLength(30)]
public string F_Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="*Enter Last Name")]
[MaxLength(30)]
public string L_Name { get; set; }

[MaxLength(30)]
public string M_Name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="*Enter Email id")]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Email{ get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="*Enter Department")]
public Int16 Dept_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Dept_Id")]
public virtual Department Dept { get; set; }
```

Department class:

```
public class Department  //static table
{
    [Key]
    public Int16 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Dept_Name { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        Faculty Id
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { style = "width:200px;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id,null, new { style="color:Red"})
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        First Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.F_Name,new { style = "width:200px;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.F_Name, null, new { style="color:red;"})
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Middle Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.M_Name,new { style = "width:200px;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.M_Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Last Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.L_Name,new { style = "width:200px;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.L_Name, null, new { style="color:red;"})
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Department
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Dept_Id ,ViewBag.Dept_Id as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
        string.Empty,new { style = "width:200px;text-align:center;"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dept_Id, null, new { style="color:red;"})
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Faculty faculty)
{
    faculty.Email = faculty.F_Name + "." + faculty.L_Name + "@mitcoe.edu.in";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Faculty.Add(faculty);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    ViewBag.Dept_Id = new SelectList(db.Department, "Id", "Dept_Name", faculty.Dept_Id);
    return View(faculty);
}
```

The drop down list works fine and the ID for all the fields is fetched properly from the view.
But in the post function the modelstate is invalid as the `Dept_name` is null.
ORM creates the tables with only `Dept_Id` as a foreign key.
Why is the controller expecting `Dept_Name` also? Is anything wrong with my models?

Comment: Model binding is not happening completely.The dept class is enclosed in your faculty.how are you fetching the data.How are you mapping your entity models to view models.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto- department and faculty are 2 different tables. i used **public Int16 Dept_Id { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Dept_Id")]
public virtual Department Dept { get; set; }** to establish a foreign key relation between both the tables. Please correct me if i'm wrong. All that i want is that faculty table should have department_id as a foreign key so that these 2 tables can be related to each other. Any help from you is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The controller is expecting `Dept_Name` because:

- You are model binding to the `Faculty` class.
- `Department` is a component of `Faculty`.
- `Dept_Name` is a required field on `Department`.

`Dept_Name` is null when the model binding parses the form data,
as you do not have it as an input anywhere in you view.

Two suggestions, either:

- Have a separate `FacultyInputModel` class which is
  the parameter to the `Create` action method.  `FacultyInputModel` includes only those properties which you expect to be returned from the form;
- Or: Use `HiddenFor` with the `Dept_Name` property, so it is included in your form data posted from you view and the model state is valid.

I'd recommend the first personally.  It can be useful sometimes to separate your view models, i.e. what data you are displaying, from your input models, i.e. what data you expect to be posted back.  It does add more classes and complexity though, on the down side. See e.g. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/the-three-models-of-asp.net-mvc-apps/ for a bit about input models.

Comment: is there a better way to establish a foreign key relation? I am new to MVC and ORM. The tables that are generated is correct with department id as the foreign key to faculty table. Department table has a list of department names with their id. So why is ORM expecting Dept_Name in faculty view? shouldn't Dept_Id automatically  link to the Dept_Name from department table?

Comment: So I should keep to seperate object type `FacultyInputModel` and `FacultyModel`? I mean it will be hard too keep their properties in sync while developing the projects if they are two different things with same properties....